# Finding a Motif in DNA

Tags: performance, scala, string-algorithm, rosalind

Problem can be found here:
http://rosalind.info/problems/subs/

The question I have has to do with the performance of the two solutions provided below.

1.

```scala
  def indexOfAppearances(strand: String, subStrand: String): List[Int] = {
    def help0(x: String, y: String, accu: List[Int]): List[Int] =
      (x contains y) match {
        case true => {
          val index = (x indexOfSlice y) /* index where substring appears */
          val adjust = strand.length - x.length
          /* adjustment since the x has all the previous
               * nucleotides removed.
               */

          val newX = x.drop(index + 1).mkString
           /* here's the drop of index + 1 elements */
          help0(newX, y, (index + adjust) :: accu) /* tail recursive call */
        }
        case false => accu
      }

     help0(strand, subStrand, List()).reverse.toList.map(x => x + 1)
         //indexes are not from 0 but from 1
  }
```

2.

```scala
  val s = "ACGTACGTACGTACGT"
  val t = "GTA"

  val combs = s.sliding(t.length).zipWithIndex
  val locations = combs.collect { case (sub, i) if (sub == t) => i + 1 }
  println(locations.mkString(" "))
```

The second solution is pretty, functional and short.

First solution is a bit large but it's still functional. I could have left out the val's and just work with the values to make it shorter but that wasn't my goal.

After seeing the 2nd solution I was quite disappointed by mine due to the length of code. Checked the scala library to see why the 2nd solution works and then re-implemented it myself.
Thought about checking the performance of both solutions and made a huge 30 million DNA strand.

Surprised!

Performance:

First number is the DNA length, and the next two numbers present the execution time of 1st and 2nd solution(in ms).

> 11,226,096 - 4921 - 14503
>
> 33,678,288 - 6448 - 35150

**Why is the performance so much different?**

I've tried checking the scala library but couldn't find a thing which explains this behaviour.

I assumed that the first solution is creating many objects thus consuming more memory and taking a lot of time to do that but it seems that for some reason it works much faster.
I doubt it's the tail recursion and I doubt that zipWithIndex takes a lot of time. Iterators are just iterators?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, what is the point of using pattern matching against true/false? why not just `if`?

Comment: I used the if first, changed it for reasons unknown, I was probably doing something else and eventually realized it was unnecessary and then just made quick edit.

Comment: Just realized the 2nd solution is yours. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sliding` isn't efficient with strings.  It breaks the string down into characters, boxes them, then reassembles them into a string.

The fastest way to do this which is still not incredibly hard is with the `regionMatches` method on `String`.  (Faster yet with DNA is to convert everything into bytes, faster yet is to convert it into 2-bit nibbles and pack into int arrays.)

Comment: Would applying this algorithm provide a quicker implementation too?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm

Comment: @Leolinus - Probably, but KMP works best with a large number of distinct characters.  The extra logic is often not worth it when your jumps are short.  Other strategies are likely to give bigger gains for less effort.